# How to use OnActorBeginOverlap in UE4 C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm working on a small game in UE4 and hit a small issue.

So far, I've got the player dealing damage to enemies (via raycast/line trace) all in C++. Now I'm trying to make the enemy cause damage to the player when their collision boxes overlap.

The player uses the `TakeDamage()` function as does the enemy to deal damage to each other.

Currently, the enemy does deal damage to the player with this Blueprint setup when both of the collisons overlap.
[image: ABAsicZombie BP]

I'm trying to translate this into C++.
I have been looking at many websites which say to use either `OnActorBeginOverlap()` or `OnComponentBeginOverlap()` with the `AddDynamic()` function. However, when trying to call `OnActorBeginOverlap()` it doesn't appear when I do `BoxCollider->` but `OnComponentBeginOverlap()` does, but does not have the `AddDynamic()` function. From what I understand, AddDynamic is a macro which I'm not too familiar with. `OnActorBeginOverlap()` does appear without the `BoxCollider->`. Both objects are Actors.

Any ideas?

Code Example:

**BasicZombie.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Components/BoxComponent.h"
#include "BasicZombie.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class MERCENARIES_API ABasicZombie : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    ABasicZombie();

    void Destroy();

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
        UBoxComponent* BoxCollider;

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    virtual float TakeDamage(float DamageAmount, struct FDamageEvent const& DamageEvent, class AController* EventInstigator, AActor* DamageCauser) override;



private:
    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly)
        float maxHealth = 100.0f;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
        float health;

    void DealDamage();
public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

};
```

**BasicZombie.cpp**

```
#include "BasicZombie.h"
#include "MainCharacter.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "DrawDebugHelpers.h"
#include "Engine/Engine.h"

// Sets default values
ABasicZombie::ABasicZombie()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = false;

    BoxCollider = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("BoxCollider"));
    BoxCollider->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AMainCharacter::OnCollision);

    health = maxHealth;


    
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void ABasicZombie::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    
    
}

float ABasicZombie::TakeDamage(float DamageAmount, struct FDamageEvent const& DamageEvent, class AController* EventInstigator, AActor* DamageCauser)
{
    float DamageToApply = Super::TakeDamage(DamageAmount, DamageEvent, EventInstigator, DamageCauser);
    DamageToApply = FMath::Min(health, DamageToApply);
    health -= DamageToApply;
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, (TEXT("Health Remaining: %f")), health);
    //GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 3.0f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT("Health Remaining: %f"), health));
    
    Destroy();

    return DamageToApply;
}

//void ABasicZombie::DealDamage()
//{
//  
//}



void ABasicZombie::Destroy()
{
    if (health <= 0)
    {
        UWorld* WorldRef = GetWorld();
        AMainCharacter* mainCharacter = Cast<AMainCharacter>(WorldRef->GetFirstPlayerController()->GetCharacter());
        mainCharacter->currentScore += 500;
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 3.0f, FColor::Green, FString::Printf(TEXT("Score: %i"), mainCharacter->currentScore));
        AActor::Destroy();
    }
}

// Called every frame
void ABasicZombie::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
}
```

**MainCharacter.h**

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"

#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"
#include "Components/CapsuleComponent.h"
#include "Components/InputComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/PlayerController.h"
#include "MainCharacter.generated.h"

class AHandgun;

UCLASS()
class MERCENARIES_API AMainCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this character's properties
    AMainCharacter();

    void OnCollision(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComponent, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& Hit);

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    virtual float TakeDamage(float DamageAmount, struct FDamageEvent const& DamageEvent, class AController* EventInstigator, AActor* DamageCauser) override;

    

private:
    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly)
        TSubclassOf<AHandgun> HandgunClass;

    UPROPERTY()
        AHandgun* Handgun;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

    //Handles Input for moving FORWARD and BACK
    UFUNCTION()
        void MoveForward(float value);

    //Handles input for moving RIGHT and LEFT
    UFUNCTION()
        void MoveRight(float value);

    UFUNCTION()
        void Shoot();

    UFUNCTION()
        void printHealth();

    //FPS camera
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
        UCameraComponent* MainCharacterCameraComponent;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Gameplay)
        FVector MuzzleOffset;

    UPROPERTY()
        int32 playerScore;

    UPROPERTY()
        int32 currentScore;

    UPROPERTY()
        float maxHealth = 1000.0f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        float currentHealth;

};
```

**MainCharacter.cpp**

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "MainCharacter.h"
#include "Engine/Engine.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Handgun.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "Components/SkeletalMeshComponent.h"


// Sets default values
AMainCharacter::AMainCharacter()
{
    // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    //Create a first person camera component
    MainCharacterCameraComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("FirstPersonCamera"));
    check(MainCharacterCameraComponent != nullptr);

    //Attach the camera component to our capsule component
    MainCharacterCameraComponent->SetupAttachment(CastChecked<USceneComponent, UCapsuleComponent>(GetCapsuleComponent()));

    //Position the camera slightly above the eyes
    MainCharacterCameraComponent->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f + BaseEyeHeight));

    //Enable the pawn to control camera rotation
    MainCharacterCameraComponent->bUsePawnControlRotation = true;

    

    currentHealth = maxHealth;
    playerScore = currentScore;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMainCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    

    check(GEngine != nullptr);
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("[MainCharacter DEBUG] - MainCharacter in use."));
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Green, FString::Printf(TEXT("[MainCharacter DEBUG] - Current Score: %f"), playerScore));

    Handgun = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AHandgun>(HandgunClass);
    Handgun->AttachToComponent(GetMesh(), FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform, TEXT("WeaponSocket"));
    Handgun->SetOwner(this);
    
    
}

// Called every frame
void AMainCharacter::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
    //printHealth();

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AMainCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    //Set up movement bindings.
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, &AMainCharacter::MoveForward);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveRight", this, &AMainCharacter::MoveRight);

    //Set up Look Bindings
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("Turn", this, &AMainCharacter::AddControllerYawInput);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("LookUp", this, &AMainCharacter::AddControllerPitchInput);

    //Setup Weapon Shooting
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction(TEXT("Fire"), EInputEvent::IE_Pressed, this, &AMainCharacter::Shoot);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction(TEXT("printHealth"), EInputEvent::IE_Pressed, this, &AMainCharacter::printHealth);

}

void AMainCharacter::Shoot()
{
    Handgun->Shoot();
}

void AMainCharacter::printHealth()
{
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Green, FString::Printf(TEXT("[MainCharacter DEBUG] - Current Health: %f"), currentHealth));
}

float AMainCharacter::TakeDamage(float DamageAmount, struct FDamageEvent const& DamageEvent, class AController* EventInstigator, AActor* DamageCauser)
{

    float DamageToApply = Super::TakeDamage(DamageAmount, DamageEvent, EventInstigator, DamageCauser);
    DamageToApply = FMath::Min(currentHealth, DamageToApply);
    currentHealth -= DamageToApply;

    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 3.0f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT("Health Remaining: %f"), currentHealth));
    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 3.0f, FColor::Red, TEXT("You're Dead!"));
    }

    return DamageAmount;
}

void AMainCharacter::MoveForward(float value)
{
    //Find out which way is "forward" and reocrd that the player wants to move that way
    FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(Controller->GetControlRotation()).GetScaledAxis(EAxis::X);
    AddMovementInput(Direction, value);
}

void AMainCharacter::MoveRight(float value)
{
    //Find out which way is "right" and record that the player wants to move that way
    FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(Controller->GetControlRotation()).GetScaledAxis(EAxis::Y);
    AddMovementInput(Direction, value);
}
```

However, the `BoxCollider->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AMainCharacter::OnCollision);` in BasicZombie.cpp has a red line under AddDynamic.

[image]

I am in a Discord Server for UE4 development, but I haven't had much luck getting any help from there.

Answer (score 0):

Can I see your C++ code? Are you calling AddDynamic from the UBoxComponent?
Try this

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
     UBoxComponent* BoxCollider = nullptr;
```

```
BoxCollider = GetOwner()->FindComponentByClass<UBoxComponent>();
BoxCollider->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &YourActor::OnCollision);
```

Use this as your OnCollision signature

```
void OnCollision(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComponent, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& Hit);
```

Also when I was learning unreal engine I dealt with a lot of pitfalls. Try to find a community of unreal engine developers and learn with them.

Comment: When I use your example for UBoxComponent = nullptr, my editor crashes. I'll edit the post above with some code examples.

Comment: Can you try FindComponentByClass?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have tried the UBoxComponent* BoxCollider = nullptr; with the BoxCollider->FindComponentByClass and as soon as I compile, the editor crashes.